# realizar una validación por periodo, compararlos si son iguales

Tags: php

[!php objetos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6hQN.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6hQN.jpg)

yo tengo una consulta que me trae un array con varios objetos necesito realizar una validación por periodo compararlos si son iguales para sacar un porcentaje[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Osea quiero entrar ese array y traer por periodo comparar si son iguales los periodos y sacarle el porcentaje